# UIWebView loading image using a callback

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiimage

I would like to know how to request images using some type of callback feature while requesting html pages from my server for my UIWebView. Currently I have no idea how a `UIWebView` downloads the image thats on a webpage, dose it use a callback? can it receive embedded image data etc, I am hoping someone can please explain the options open to me.

I have looked all through apple docs URLConnection, NSURLConnection, UIWebView etc and there is no explanations on the different ways UIWebView load images, so I am hoping someone can help explain to me the different ways a UIWebView can request the images for display and what I should look out for on my server end to make things easier.

So the reason for this question is that I need to decide on how best to store the images on my server or other things like is it better to embed the images in the html response, are callbacks support etc etc..

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just load images. No callbacks, delegates, notifications or smth. If your image is reachable via browser, it'll be downloaded and presented by UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know what delegates are but what are `notifications or smth` how do they work? .. right dose it mean something? LOL first time I have heard that acronym.

Comment: Yep, it's for something :) Notifications - `NSNotification` objects, the special kind of inter-object communication. But `UIWebView` doesn't use it at all.