# How does UIWebView process imags found in HTML?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I would like to know how the `UIWebView` handles images when receiving HTML from a standard `NSURLRequest`. For instance if I had the following HTML;

```
<body>
  <!-- header -->
  <header>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="60" alt="pingpong">
    </div>
  </header>

// then the rest of the site (txt, links, more pics etc)
</body>
```

So considering the HTML above if I were to make the following requests for this HTML like so;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.myurl.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

When 'webView' receives the 'requestObj' via the `loadRequest` call, how does the webview handle the images found in the HTML?

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="60" alt="pingpong">
```

What does the `UIWebView` do when it encounters an image like this? how does it get the image data/file etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIWebView loading image using a callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255923/uiwebview-loading-image-using-a-callback)

Comment: No its not, that was asking about callbacks.. UIWebViews do not produce callbacks.. I have done a ton of reading in apple docs and cannot find out how UIWebView retrive the image data, which this question is now referring too.

Comment: Sorry, your other question seemed to ask all these questions too. But I can see how they should have been separated anyways.

Comment: its all good..Just wish I could figure this out.

Comment: I'm curios, what is the problem you are trying to solve that needs  understanding of the core flow of the webview ?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the best way to present the images in the response. embedded data in the reply or just multiple requests that I think the uiview makes automatically or are there other possibilities.. etc.